# Re-organize database by merging rows from a variable

Tags: r, database, row, reorganize

I have a database that looks like this:

```
userId          SessionId        Screen         Platform       Version
01              1                first          IOS            1.0.1
01              1                main           IOS            1.0.1
01              2                first          IOS            1.0.1
01              3                first          IOS            1.0.1
01              3                main           IOS            1.0.1
01              3                detail         IOS            1.0.1
02              1                first          Android        1.0.2
```

Basically what I intend to do is to determine if a "path" (different screens) leads to a better retention or not. I would like to re-organize each sessionId in one column. Ideal database would look like this:

```
userId       SessionId       Path                 Retention
01           1               first;main           3
01           2               first                3
01           3               first;main;detail    3
02           1               first                1
```

Here is the variable `Retention` would be equal to the maximum `SessionId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution in base R:

```
d2 <- aggregate(Screen ~ userId + SessionId, d, toString)
transform(d2, retention = ave(Screen, userId, FUN = length))
```

which gives:

```
> d2
  userId SessionId              Screen retention
1     01         1         first, main         3
2     02         1               first         1
3     01         2               first         3
4     01         3 first, main, detail         3
```

An alternative using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(userId, SessionId) %>% 
  summarise(Screen = toString(Screen)) %>% 
  group_by(userId) %>% 
  mutate(retention = n())
```

which gives:

```
  userId SessionId              Screen retention
   <chr>     <int>               <chr>     <int>
1     01         1         first, main         3
2     01         2               first         3
3     01         3 first, main, detail         3
4     02         1               first         1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(d)
dt[, Retention := max(SessionId), by = .(userId)]
dt[, .(Screen = paste(Screen, collapse = ";"), Retention = unique(Retention)), by = .(userId, SessionId)]

userId SessionId            Screen Retention
1:     01         1        first;main         3
2:     01         2             first         3
3:     01         3 first;main;detail         3
4:     02         1             first         1
```

Comment: A cleaner alternative (at least imo): `dt[, .(Screen = toString(Screen)), by = .(userId, SessionId)][, retention := .N, by = userId][]`

Comment: I assumed that the semicolons were important and that there may be sessionIds missing.